# how to find the real value beetween numbersjava

Tags: java

Good afternoon,

Consider that we have two numbers and we want to add them but without any rounding, we want to get the real value 
so if we add 0,4+0,6 either being double or float java prints the result 1 but actually this is not the real number which is store on the memmory.
i tried to convert them into BigDecimal but it also prints the result 1!!
however converting bigDecimal works fine when numbers have franctions part except 0.5  !

this is a part of a method i am making a scientific calculator with netbeans user gives a mathematic expression in a textArea .a take the expression as a string and i seperate it giving  value to an object Mathematic element the element could be an operator or numbers.
the part of the method  i post it has only the case of adding

if user gives the expression 0.6+0.4 i want to find the both result and print them(the result that gives 0.4+0.6=1 and also the real result of this sum)

```
Stack<MathematicElement> stack = new Stack<MathematicElement>();
    BigDecimal pin[]=new BigDecimal[post.length];
    BigDecimal b1;
    BigDecimal flo[]=new BigDecimal[post.length];
    BigDecimal f1;
    float f;
    int k=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < post.length; i++) {
        if (post[i].isNumber) {
            stack.push(post[i]);
            pin[0]=new BigDecimal(post[i].number);
            flo[0]=new BigDecimal(new Float(post[i].number));
            continue;

        }
        if (post[i].isOperator) {
            MathematicElement mx2 = stack.pop();
            double modifier;
            if(system==MathematicalNumberingSystem.DEGREES)
                modifier = pi/180;
            else
                modifier = 1;
            double x2 = mx2.number, x1, y;
            float f2=new Float(x2);
            BigDecimal f22=new BigDecimal(f2);
            BigDecimal b2=new BigDecimal(x2);
            switch (post[i].operator) {
                case PLUS:
                    x1 = stack.pop().number;
                    b1=new BigDecimal(x1);
                    pin[0]=b1.add(b2);
                    f=new Float(x1);
                    f1=new BigDecimal(f);
                    flo[0]=f1.add(f22);
                    //System.out.format("the b1=%20.16f  and the b2=%20.16f \n",b1,b2);
                    y = x1 + x2;

                    //FloatingPointNumber(x1);
                    //FloatingPointNumber(x2);
                    //FloatingPointNumber(y);
                    stack.push(new MathematicElement(y));
                    k++;
```

Comment: Need to see the code....

Comment: if you don't want to round, don't use doubles.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with BigDecimal, like you did, but on this example, 1 (one) can be expressed on base 2 (two), so the computer holds the exactly value =D

Comment: can you be a little more presize please!!

Answer (score 0):

0.4d + 0.6d ends up equaling 1.0d. I believe BigDecimal will pare this down to 1d to save memory.

In other words, you already have the answer :)